# Inner object deserialization with Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson, jackson-databind, jackson-annotations

I have a json

```
{
"params": [
    {
        "key": "path",
        "options": {
            "string": {
                "prefix": "test_pref"
            }
        },
        "default": {
            "url": ""
        }
    }
]}
```

I have the following POJO class, where i want to map inner objects like option.string.prefix in json to prefix in Params POJO class.

```
@Data
@Accessors(chain = true)
public class Data {
    private List<Params> params;
}

@Data
@Accessors(chain = true)
public class Params {

    private String key;

    @JsonProperty("options.string.prefix")
    private String prefix;

    @JsonProperty("default.url")
    private String url;
}
```

Is there any Jackson annotation that helps me do this without @JsonProperty?

Comment: I don't think Jackson can do this out of the box. `@JsonProperty` as used will probably result in a JSON object as `{ "options.string.prefix": "test_pref", ... }`(not what you want). There is an annotation, `@JsonUnwrapped` that does the *opposite* of what you want. You will probably have to resort to custom `JsonDeserializer`/`JsonSerializer` implementations.

Answer (score 0):

The is `@JsonGetter` which is an alternative to  `@JsonProperty` You can read a very nice article on the topic here: [Jackson Annotation Examples](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-annotations)